# Detect if an IP is local or public

Tags: java, ip, local, lan

I have a Java server where I need to check if an IP is local or public when I get a connection. 
I can detect it when its my own local IP but I'm having some trouble with other local IPs.
Does Java give us a way to do it? I haven't found it, so probably we should convert IP to numbers and check if is in the local IP range. How can I get this range?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address

Answer (score 2):

The private IP ranges are:

```
10.0.0.0/8 (from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255) [ Named as Class A Private Network ]

172.16.0.0/12 (from 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255) [ Named as Class B Private Network ]

192.168.0.0/16 (from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255) [ Named as Class C Private Network ]
```

Comment: Whether Ip is private and public can be clarified by above IP range matrix which is for private IP. Other than these IP, it will be public IP.  There nothing JAVA or any other programming language specific logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate your question. From my understanding you want to check whether the IP lies inside 192.x.x.x or outside the range. If that is the case just a string or integer comparision will solve your question.

Comment: 192.x.x.x is not the only local/private IP range

Comment: @GermannArlington yes/maybe. I just gave the idea/thought to implement

Comment: It would be good to point the OP in the right direction, not offer them an idea of partial implementation...

Answer (score 0):

An IP address within one of three ranges are used within local networks only (behind routers and firewalls) and considered as private IP address ranges.

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

I don't think Java provide such a way to tell if an IP address is private or public. I think you have to write your own function.